# Completely different UI for iPad in a universal app

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I usually use autolayout together with size classes, to optimize the UI for larger screens, like on iPad.

However, sometimes I need a completely different layout for the UI on iPad, still containing the same view controllers, but structured differently.

What is the best strategies in such situation, where autolayout and size classes are not enough? Loading a different storyboard for iPad?

Obviously the goal here is to not introduce any code duplication.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do same thing with size classes on UIViews and NSLayoutConstraints, for an example if i have different views for pad and phone, but i must do same logic for sections, i create two different views in same storyboard and enable/disable views based on size classes

Comment: I see, when you say "enable/disable", do you mean the hidden property?

Comment: no i mean you can install and unisntall view from storyboard

Answer (score 2):

> Loading a different storyboard for iPad? Obviously the goal here is to not introduce any code duplication.

If that's what you want to do, that feature is built-in and expected. You don't need any code at all. Just create your two storyboards and edit the *Info.plist* so that it has two main storyboard entries that point to them:

[image]

The right thing will just happen: on iPad, the second storyboard will load at launch.

Comment: Working downloadable example (from my book) here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk1ch09p358universal - look in the Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Make Use of 2 Views(xib) with a single class file. The number of connections has to be same in both xibs but the placement of elements can be different for iPad and iPhone.

[image]

Here Below is my code to load XIB from a viewcontroller.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var customView:CustomView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    loadCustomView()
}

func loadCustomView(){
    if  let appDelegate =  UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
        let window = appDelegate.window {
        customView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: window.frame.width, height: window.frame.height))
        window.addSubview(customView!)
    }
}
}
```

Then there is the UIView Class

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var lbl_Title: UILabel!

var view:UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    setup()
}

func setup() {

    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleWidth
    view.autoresizingMask = UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleHeight
    addSubview(view)
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone{
        let bundle = Bundle(for:type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }else{
        let bundle = Bundle(for:type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomViewTab", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }

}
}
```

You make the outlet connections to both the XIBs from this class and load the views depending on device type.

Comment: And how do you load a xib over the other? You check programmatically if it's an ipad?